# Cannot deserialize instance of class

Tags: java, json, api, spring

Tengo una API REST corriendo en intelij y no me esta andando la consulta que quiero hacer sobre un metodo post. No estoy entendiendo porque me esta diciendo que no puede deserializar el [json](/questions/tagged/json) cuando estoy implementando la interfaz en mi clase

//Estoy trabajando con un api rest y cuando le mando este json:
    //{"text": "HOLA MELI"}

```
//No me anda con la siguiente clase:

    package MorseCode;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class MorseResponse implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5529613997641578535L;

        private String text;

        public MorseResponse(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
        public void setText(String user) {
            this.text = text;
        }

    }
```

Y con el siguiente codigo:

```
    package MorseCode;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "/translate")
    public class RestUser {

        @RequestMapping(
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                path = "/2Morse",
                consumes = "application/json",
                produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        MorseResponse toMorse(@RequestBody MorseResponse string) {
            MorseCode morseCode = new MorseCode();
            return new MorseResponse(morseCode.translate2Morse(string.getText()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, un vistazo a  [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] te serviría para mejorar tu pregunta y tener mayor posibilidad de respuesta. Podrías colocar el stack completo para poder entender mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0):

1.Por defecto spring trabaja con json. Si deseas puedes intentarlo con el siguiente código.

2.Por lo que veo necesitas una clase repo, service, Impl, ademas tienes que manejar la inyección de dependencias con la amada
    @Autowired. Lo basico que se necesita para levantar un API

```
@PostMapping(value = "2Morse")
    public MorseResponse toMorse(@Valid @RequestBody MorseResponse string) {
        MorseCode morseCode = new MorseCode();
        return new MorseResponse(morseCode.translate2Morse(string.getText()));
    }
```